# Javascript - IE8 alternative to bind()

Tags: javascript

```
img.attachEvent("onclick", function(img){

 alert(img.id);

}.bind(null,img));
```

How can i make this work in IE 8? Or what is the most direct alternative?

Comment: I'd rather not thanks

Comment: The above two comments are quite exciting duel between jQuery vs. plain javascript fans :-)

Comment: The clue is in the title, it's a Javascript question not a jQuery question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a polyfill [here](https://gist.github.com/dsingleton/1312328).

```
Function.prototype.bind = Function.prototype.bind || function(b) {
    if (typeof this !== "function") {
      throw new TypeError("Function.prototype.bind - what is trying to be bound is not callable");
    }

    var a = Array.prototype.slice;
    var f = a.call(arguments, 1);
    var e = this;
    var c = function() {};
    var d = function() {
      return e.apply(this instanceof c ? this : b || window, f.concat(a.call(arguments)));
    };

    c.prototype = this.prototype;
    d.prototype = new c();

    return d;
};
```

Comment: Great link +1, Thanks! See [Polyfill by developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility). This answer helped html2canvas lib: [html2canvas not working in iOS 5 devices](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/issues/365)

Answer (score 1):

Use `event.srcElement`:

```
img.attachEvent("onclick", function(ev){
    alert(ev.srcElement.id);
});
```

I would give you a JSFiddle, but JSFiddle fails in IE8.

**EDIT:** Another solution would to use a closure/variable solution.  Something like this:

```
(function(){
    var _img=img;
    _img.attachEvent("onclick",function(ev){
        alert(_img.id);
    });
})();
```

This creates a local copy of `img` so you can use it inside the event listener.

Beyond that my advice is to just forget IE 8 altogether.  (J/K)

Comment: Sorry that's just a basic example I need to pass other variables

Comment: Then you should probably either use a closure/variables solution or use the polyfill mentioned in @JanTuroň's answer.

Answer (score -3):

I thought of adding this as comment, but made me to post. "**Please use jQuery and save your time from these type of issues.**"

if happen to use `jQuery` in near future.

```
$(document).on('click', '.class', function() {
    // code here
});
```

There is a good `compatability` script on this page below. Just **copy and paste** it into your script.
http://dochub.io/#javascript/function.bind

Comment: Can anyone tell me whats wrong with the answer before downvoting, so that i can correct.

Comment: He _just barely_ said `I'd rather not thanks` about using jQuery.  I think that's why you got downvoted (Just a guess.  I wasn't the one who did it.)

Comment: Thats fine, everyone is entitled of their opinion that does not mean the answer is wrong and more over towards the context of the question i have given the answer for alternative approach.

Comment: They claim the compatibility script works with IE9...