# Variable is undefined/out of scope

Tags: javascript

This is a scope issue, correct?

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/RPwLK/7/

On line 38 of the following function, where displayBossMessage() is called by itself, the variable "boss" seems to be out of scope. It should contain the name (string) of the current boss, and when the function is called, it should put it back in the "boss" argument.

But boss seems to always be undefined. I've tried creating a variable right before the jQuery listener is created to see if it would be within scope, but it seems as if it isn't.

Or maybe I'm just having a slow day. ;p

```
function displayBossMessage(boss,message,options,timer){
    boss = bosses[boss];

    //clear any possible lingering text/buttons
    $(boss.messagebox).text('');
    $(boss.optionsbox).text('');
    displayMessage_CurrentBoss = boss;

    //if no options provided, set a default "continue" button
    if(options == ''){
        options = {
            'default' : {
                'text' : 'Continue',
                'func' : function(){}
            }
        }
    }

    $('#container div').hide();
    $(boss.div).fadeIn(1500);

    writeMessage(message,$(boss.messagebox),0);

    setTimeout(function(){
        $(boss.optionsbox).fadeIn(1000);
    },3000);

    //"listen" for a choice
    var i = 0;
    for(option in options){
        $(boss.optionsbox).html($(boss.optionsbox).html() + '<button name="'+ i +'">'+ options[option].text +'</button> &nbsp;');

        $(document).on('click', (boss.div)+' button[name="'+i+'"]', function(){
            options[option].func();

            //close message screen or show defined response
            if(typeof options[option].response != 'undefined'){
                displayBossMessage(boss,options[option].response,'',true);
            }else{
                $(boss.div).hide();
                $('#container div').fadeIn(1500);
            }

        });
    }

    if(timer){
        //if they are afk/don't click after a minute, do it for them
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(boss.div+' button[name="0"]').click();
        },60000);
    }
}
```

Hope I'm not being completely oblivious and missing something so simple.

**Edit: Bosses variable (is global) **

Comment: the basic problem here is the wrong use of an closure variable in a loop

Comment: What's `bosses[]` - globally declared array?

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451009/javascript-infamous-loop-problem

Comment: Got a working example that we can just open in the browser, like a jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Sure, I'll make one right now

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I believe I've made a working test, http://jsfiddle.net/RPwLK/7/

Comment: @user3029571 - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'messagebox' of undefined `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*updated jsfiddle revision link to #11 which includes both solutions*)

Looks like this could be a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RPwLK/11/

A minor problem: you have an extra `'` on line 30 with the (second) `alert` call - the string literal was not closed correctly (or rather another was being opened). After that I was able to investigate and come up with the following conclusion (2 problems)...

---

**The first problem was with the variable override** here:

```
function displayBossMessage(boss,message,options,timer){
    boss = bosses[boss]; // this line, boss was a string, now it will be an object
```

And the later usage in the same function here:

```
if(typeof options[option].response != 'undefined'){
    displayBossMessage(boss,options[option].response,'',true); // first arg is now an object
```

**The solution is to** create a reference to the original `boss` when it was a string like:

```
function displayBossMessage(boss,message,options,timer){
    var origBoss = boss; // let's remember what it was in its original string form
    boss = bosses[boss];
```

And use it like so:

```
if(typeof options[option].response != 'undefined'){
    displayBossMessage(origBoss,options[option].response,'',true); // now we're dealing with a string ref
```

---

The second problem is the reference to `option` within the `for` loop. It was always referencing the *last* value since the `$(document).on('click'...` is always delayed (asynchronous). There are a number of ways to solve this. I chose to use `bind` and pass in an argument with a reference to the value of `option` for each specific iteration.

Notice that in the original `option` is in the async function but not in a closure (`for` is not a closure):

```
for(option in options){
    //...
    $(document).on('click', (boss.div)+' button[name="'+i+'"]', function(){
        options[option].func(); // here option is always the last item in options
```

So introduce an argument conveniently called `option` in the callback function for the click handler:

```
$(document).on('click', (boss.div)+' button[name="'+i+'"]', function(option){ // here
    options[option].func(); // and now option is whatever the argument value is
```

And don't forget to pass it in the function declaration via bind:

```
    $(document).on('click', (boss.div)+' button[name="'+i+'"]', function(option){
        options[option].func();
        // ...
    }.bind(this,option)); // here we're passing whatever option is for the specific iteration as the first argument of the callback function
```

Note, `this` is just the scope, and each subsequent parameter for [`bind` (see MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) after the first corresponds to the arguments in the function definition.

Comment: Aah! Thank you. I'm such an idiot sometimes. Also, sorry for originally supplying the wrong link. Thanks again!

Comment: @user3029571 np, it happens, i updated the question with the solution to a secondary problem - bonus!

Comment: Wow, I did not see that one coming. You probably saved me an hour or two of trying to figure out what was going on. I appreciate it, again!

Comment: @user3029571 yup! there are some other problems too (lots of alerts), but i'll leave those for you (or perhaps another SO question). also, be weary of `bind` since its not supported in all browsers, [here are some alternatives (SO question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022712/javascript-ie8-alternative-to-bind) *oh and once you get 15 rep, an upvote for a +10 would be cool, thanks!*

Comment: I will most definitely come back and vote you up. :)