# These code can run in Chrome, but not in IE8. How to fix it correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the part in my test file , Chrome can run the console.log value, but not in IE8. How to fix the code that make the IE8 can run the same circumstance ?

```
<script>
var f = function () {
    console.log(this.name);
};

var another = f.bind({ name: 'welcome' });


another();  // welcome
</script>
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: which part fails and with what error?

Comment: First step if something doesn't work in IE: check if every function is supported by IE -> https://caniuse.com/#search=bind, http://caniuse.com/#search=console

Comment: probably need [this polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind#Polyfill)

Comment: `bind` isn't supported [until IE9](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

Comment: both bind and console won't work on IE

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20022712/javascript-ie8-alternative-to-bind

Comment: @i-- - console.log was introduced in IE8, so, ...

Comment: Stop supporting IE8

Comment: @JaromandaX canIuse say IE11. and I don't have an IE 8 to test

Comment: My error is when I use chrome to check the value of console.log in chrome, there is 'welcome'. But, in the IE8, there is nothing. No console.log in IE8.

Comment: Surely there's something in the console ... like an error message ... perhaps something like **Object doesn't support property or method 'bind'**

Comment: @i-- - I see full support since IE10, and problematic support in 8 and 9 (only available when console is open, otherwise throws an error)